# Android: 60 fps in Debug mode but slow down in Release mode

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, compiler-optimization, frame-rate

I wrote a game for Android (using Android Studio, Gradle, the Java Framework with OpenGL ES 2.0 without NDK, the game is 3D) I have reached a speed of about 60fps in debug mode.
When I build the Release version the frames rate drops dramatically.
I tried:

-Build in release without optimization and obfuscation.
-I tested with different optimizations (especially for inline code)
-I tried many different devices, but all more or less feel the drop in frames rate.

The release version is more faster than debug only for assets load time.
I believe that the compilation only favors small code size, but not the speed of the code (which notoriously consume more memory and increases the size of the code, Gradle does not seem to treat the problem with Java compiler).

Does anyone know any specific reason for this circumstance. It's really frustrating to work to achieve an appropriate speed and then lose it for some tools silly problem.

-Update

Frame rate is almost constant but is below 30 fps (on the same device).
The thing I find inexplicable is that in debug mode the game is really fluid and clear as it should be, even with all the active logs.
This is my first Android game, but I have twenty years of experience on other platforms in graphical programming and graphics engines.
I think it may be the interference of some of Android service that limits the speed of the game to save energy.
I do not use external libraries for the main loop of the game, there are no loads of memory during the loop (the memory is constant in debug).
I do not have much experience in debuging release versions of Android ('ll look more carefully, but I doubt that it's the fault of my code).
Thanks for the answers anyway.

-Update 2

Using the tracer for the CPU of Android Studio, it appears that the release version frames are faster than those of the Debug version, as it should be.
For me the cause of slowing down is out of my code (for now).
No one is this thing happened?

-Update 3

Link to systrace (work only width Chrome Browser):

[Release systrace](http://www.d3gsoft.com/debug/trace.html)

[Debug systrace](http://www.d3gsoft.com/debug/traceDebug.html)

-Update 4

I noticed this when compiling:

**RELEASE**
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleRelease]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkReleaseManifest
:app:pre**Debug**Build UP-TO-DATE <=====What? Is it normal?
...

---

**DEBUG**
Executing tasks: [:app:incrementalDebugSupportDex]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
Incremental java compilation is an incubating feature.
:app:buildInfoDebugLoader
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:pre**Release**Build UP-TO-DATE <=====What is?

Is there a way to edit the tasks of Gradle?

Comment: Are you really sure it is a problem with the tool? In any case I have just one adcice: Profile the heck out of your app and figure out what's the problem. From just the information in your question I doubt anyone could help you.

Comment: Maybe you have some concurrency problems (say, some code becomes faster in release mode and executes more often blocking some other code, what affecting fps).. Please define "frames rate drops dramatically". Please try to make minimal sample or find performance bottleneck in your code and post it.

Comment: In general the release certain will always be much faster because all the debug related code isn't included.

Comment: Yes what @Anton said is exactly what's my suspicion too. Profiling is the only way to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Does the framerate increase if you touch the screen while it's rendering?

Comment: I thought it would be a problem of libraries that remain constant in debug but use "new" in the release. I replaced all classes of Android that could change the size of objects during the loop of the game with other classes who can not do it. I tried to temporarily remove the sound code, AI and physics. The input does not seem to affect the frame rate.

Answer (score 0):

This is a partial solution.

I just replaced a function that called another function with an inline function:

**Original**

```
public void ParentChildrenMatrix(final D3GMATRIX ResultMatrix, final D3GModel3D Model)
{

    D3GModel3D P = Model;


    ResultMatrix.copy(Model.WorldMatrix);

    while(P.Parent != null)
    {

        D3GMATRIX.multiplyMM(Hierarchy, P.Parent.WorldMatrix, ResultMatrix);

        ResultMatrix.copy(Hierarchy);

        P = P.Parent;
    }

}
```

**Alternative procedure**

```
public void ParentChildrenMatrix(final D3GMATRIX ResultMatrix, final D3GModel3D Model)
{

    D3GModel3D P = Model;


    ResultMatrix.copy(Model.WorldMatrix);

    while(P.Parent != null)
    {

        Hierarchy.M[_11] = (ResultMatrix.M[_11] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_11]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_12] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_21]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_13] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_31]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_14] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_41]);
        Hierarchy.M[_12] = (ResultMatrix.M[_11] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_12]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_12] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_22]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_13] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_32]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_14] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_42]);
        Hierarchy.M[_13] = (ResultMatrix.M[_11] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_13]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_12] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_23]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_13] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_33]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_14] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_43]);
        Hierarchy.M[_14] = (ResultMatrix.M[_11] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_14]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_12] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_24]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_13] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_34]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_14] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_44]);

        Hierarchy.M[_21] = (ResultMatrix.M[_21] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_11]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_22] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_21]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_23] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_31]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_24] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_41]);
        Hierarchy.M[_22] = (ResultMatrix.M[_21] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_12]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_22] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_22]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_23] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_32]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_24] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_42]);
        Hierarchy.M[_23] = (ResultMatrix.M[_21] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_13]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_22] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_23]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_23] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_33]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_24] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_43]);
        Hierarchy.M[_24] = (ResultMatrix.M[_21] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_14]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_22] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_24]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_23] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_34]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_24] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_44]);

        Hierarchy.M[_31] = (ResultMatrix.M[_31] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_11]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_32] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_21]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_33] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_31]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_34] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_41]);
        Hierarchy.M[_32] = (ResultMatrix.M[_31] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_12]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_32] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_22]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_33] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_32]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_34] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_42]);
        Hierarchy.M[_33] = (ResultMatrix.M[_31] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_13]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_32] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_23]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_33] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_33]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_34] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_43]);
        Hierarchy.M[_34] = (ResultMatrix.M[_31] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_14]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_32] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_24]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_33] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_34]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_34] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_44]);

        Hierarchy.M[_41] = (ResultMatrix.M[_41] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_11]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_42] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_21]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_43] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_31]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_44] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_41]);
        Hierarchy.M[_42] = (ResultMatrix.M[_41] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_12]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_42] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_22]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_43] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_32]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_44] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_42]);
        Hierarchy.M[_43] = (ResultMatrix.M[_41] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_13]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_42] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_23]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_43] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_33]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_44] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_43]);
        Hierarchy.M[_44] = (ResultMatrix.M[_41] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_14]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_42] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_24]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_43] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_34]) + (ResultMatrix.M[_44] * P.Parent.WorldMatrix.M[_44]);

        System.arraycopy(Hierarchy.M, 0, ResultMatrix.M, 0, 16);



       P = P.Parent;
    }

}
```

However I did not understand why the original function in the debug version was running much faster than in the old release version.
The only valid reason is that in release the function is "optimized" incorrectly (better leave it not optimized).